How to convert a file to format accepted by PrimeNG file uploader?
I am using angular with primeng.
I have the following scenario:
I receive an image from an api, that in turn I want to push into the files array of the primeng file uploader to populate it with my file.
However, the issue arises with the formats being used:
The format that I get my data in is the following:
{
  "fileName": "eevee.png",
  "content": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdsAAAHbCAYAAACDe...",
  "contentType": "image/png",
  "fullPath": "D:\\storage\\surveys\\cache\\1142\\6712\\eevee.png",
  "base64Content": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdsAAAHbCAYAAACDe...",
  "length": 142266
}

After receiving this file, I convert the base64 value to a File object with this helper function:
base64toFile(base64String: string, filename: string): File {
    // Split the base64 string to get the data part
    const base64Data = base64String.split(',')[1];

    // Convert the base64 string to a binary array
    const binaryString = window.atob(base64Data);

    // Create a blob object from the binary data
    const blob = new Blob([binaryString], { type: 'image/png' });

    // Create a File object from the blob
    const file = new File([blob], filename, { type: 'image/png' });

    return file;
  }

Now here is the issue, the after selecting a file in primeng, it is stored internally with this format, a File object and an additional property:

This is my code inside a custom component where I want to populate the file uploader:
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.fileUpload && this.control?.value) {
        const primeNgFormatFile = {
          ...this.control.value,
          objectURL: {
            changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: URL.createObjectURL(
              this.control.value
            ),
          },
        };
        this.fileUpload._files.push(primeNgFormatFile);
        this.fileUpload.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    }, 0);
  }

What I expect to see:

What I see now:


Could you try changing the reference of the array this.fileUpload._files using array de-structuring, which might trigger the refresh?
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.fileUpload && this.control?.value) {
        const primeNgFormatFile = {
          ...this.control.value,
          objectURL: {
            changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: URL.createObjectURL(
              this.control.value
            ),
          },
        };
        this.fileUpload._files.push(primeNgFormatFile);
        this.fileUpload._files = [...this.fileUpload._files]; // <- changed here!
        this.fileUpload.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    }, 0);
  }


This does not change anything
I believe that the issue comes from the format of the file that I try to push into the files array

@codrut please share a stackblitz where the issue happens for debugging!

In the end I opted to create my own file upload component and the issue no longer persists
But the issue might have been that the file was corrupted when converting from base64 to File, I changed the code to check for invalid characters


base64toFile(base64String: string, filename: string): File {
    // Split the base64 string to get the data part
    // const base64Data = base64String.split(',')[1];

    // Convert the base64 string to a binary array
    const binaryString = window.atob(base64String);

    // Create an ArrayBuffer from the binary data
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
    const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
      view[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // Create a blob object from the ArrayBuffer using the view
    const blob = new Blob([view], { type: 'image/png' });

    // Create a File object from the blob
    const file = new File([blob], filename, { type: 'image/png' });

    return file;
  }



